# React Webpack Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Hi guys I tried to eject my webpack on may create-react-app via `npm run eject`

And then inside `config/webpack.config.js` I searched for this part:

```
 isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        // css is located in `static/css`, use '../../' to locate index.html folder
        // in production `paths.publicUrlOrPath` can be a relative path
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
```

Where I plan on using CSS module instead. So replace some setup on the options:

```
loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
options: {
  importLoaders: 1,
  modules: true,
  // This will generate these unique CSS files
  // once we import them from the object
  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
}
}
```

But this did not work. Usually webpack has two config `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.production.js`. In the end it output this error:

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals?, esModule? }
```

Any idea how to fix this?

You can check the whole webpack file here: https://jsfiddle.net/15z2v9ju/

Comment: The message is saying there is no option name `localIdentName` which means you put code in the right place but the wrong option. Try to ref to the document to have the right one

Comment: Not sure where to put it bud.. https://jsfiddle.net/15z2v9ju/
Sorry beginner here.

Comment: Are you going to change the `css-loader` options for both (dev/prod) env?

Comment: Both. I need to it to set up to CSS module...just like above. When I eject there is only one config file `config/webpack.config.js` I don't see two separate file.

Comment: I just dropped an answer for you. Hopefully it would help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I suggest to find and add more your option in the function `getStyleLoaders` where is currently being used:

```
getStyleLoaders({
  importLoaders: 1,
  modules: {
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
  },
})
```

However, seems above your config is old. `localIdentName` options is appeared to be move to `modules` instead